# Select elements with all other ID that is not 'this.id'

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have 4 elements and within `onclick()` only one of the `block` div will show;

HTML:

```
<!--elements that will toggle block div to show-->
<p onclick="expand(this.id)" id="p1"></p>
<p onclick="expand(this.id)" id="p2"></p>
<p onclick="expand(this.id)" id="p3"></p>
<p onclick="expand(this.id)" id="p4"></p>
<!--block div-->
<div id="block_p1"></div>
<div id="block_p2"></div>
<div id="block_p3"></div>
<div id="block_p4"></div>
```

JS:

```
function expand(e) {
document.getElementById("block_" + e).style.display = "block";
document.getElementById(e).style.backgroundColor = "#425a94";
}
```

**The problem is when I click the second element after the first, says I click `p2` after `p1`, the block div--`block_p1` doesn't disappear as `block_p2` is shown, *how do I hide the first block after the second is clicked?*** If I didn't use the parameter I'd do something like this:

```
function expand() {
document.getElementById("block_p2").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("p2").style.backgroundColor = "#425a94";
document.getElementById("block_p1").style.display = "none";
}
```

I don't know how to do the same in the case of the one with a parameter. Also in the case that third element is selected I need to hide the first two blocks as well.

Comment: I don't see any elements like `#expanded_p2` nor `#toolbar_expand`

Comment: Why are you using an ID for this? A class would be suitable for this

Comment: @Brainfeeder Sorry! Forgot to edit after copied from the original code. Fixed.

Comment: @pploypiti maybe the answer help you in this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **first** need to *hide* all divs that start with id `expanded_`, just add this line before rest of your code.

```
var allExpanded = document.querySelectorAll( "div[id^='expanded_']" );
Array.from( allExpanded ).forEach( s => (s.style.display = "none") );
```

Your functions becomes

```
function expand(e) 
{
    //first hide all
    var allExpanded = document.querySelectorAll( "div[id^='expanded_']" );
    Array.from( allExpanded ).forEach( s => (s.style.display = "none") );
    //then show specific
    document.getElementById("expanded_" + e).style.display = "block";

    document.getElementById(e).style.backgroundColor = "#425a94";
    document.getElementById("toolbar_expand").style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: `"div[id^='expanded_']"` is just the worst thing I've ever seen. It's like you're 100% sure there won't be any other divs with IDs in the document, which is statistically wrong.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir It is okay for this question though... I use selectors like that sometimes, if ID's are named like they should, there would not be any danger in 'being 100% sure there won't be any other divs with ID's like that in the document'. (although 'expanded_' is rather general and could be used somewhere else...)

Comment: @Brainfeeder Fair enough. Although a (specially picked) class would've been better.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir  === (bool)true

Answer (score 1):

[From my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49977912/1377002), a small amendment to pick up all display elements which can be looped over in the function to remove the class that was previously added:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
});

function handleClick(e) {
  const id = e.target.dataset.id;
  slides.forEach(slide => slide.classList.remove('show'));
  const slide = document.querySelector(`.slide[data-id="${id}"]`);
  slide.classList.add('show');
}
```

```css
.slide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p class="button" data-id="1">icon1</p>
<p class="button" data-id="2">icon2</p>
<p class="button" data-id="3">icon3</p>
<div class="slide" data-id="1">blocki1</div>
<div class="slide" data-id="2">blocki2</div>
<div class="slide" data-id="3">blocki3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `id` match selector to get all the `div` with `id` having `block_` as substring and then hide all of them except the clicked one.

```js
function expand(id) {
  document.getElementById('block_'+id).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "#425a94";
  document.querySelectorAll('[id^="block_"]').forEach(function(elem){
   if(elem.id !== 'block_'+id){
     elem.style.display = "none";
     var pId = elem.id.split('_')[1];
     document.getElementById(pId).style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
   }
  });
}
```

```css
div{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<!--elements that will toggle block div to show-->
<p onclick="expand(this.id)" id="p1">p1 click</p>
<p onclick="expand(this.id)" id="p2">p2 click</p>
<p onclick="expand(this.id)" id="p3">p3 click</p>
<p onclick="expand(this.id)" id="p4">p4 click</p>
<!--block div-->
<div id="block_p1">P1</div>
<div id="block_p2">P2</div>
<div id="block_p3">P3</div>
<div id="block_p4">P4</div>
```